# how to use two roles as a and operator in cerbos

Tags: c#, permissions, roles, cerbos

I am using Cerbos (https://www.cerbos.dev/) to implement user permission level,

I have defined a derived role like this:

```
description: |-
  Lending abc derived role
derivedRoles:
  name: abc_user_derived_role
  definitions:
    - name: abc_user
    parentRoles: ["customer_user", "api_user"]
    condition:
      match:
        expr: ("abc_id" in P.attr) && (P.attr.abc_id != "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
```

Now in the "`loan`" resource yml file, I want an action called "`read_funding_amount`" which can be allowed if a user have either `customer_user` or `api_user` And  Admin role

I got the code below in the `loan.yml` file:

```
resourcePolicy:
version: "default"
resource: "loan"
importDerivedRoles:
  - abc_user_derived_role
rules:
 - actions:
  - read_funding_amount
 effect: EFFECT_ALLOW
 derivedRoles:
   - abc_user
 roles:
  - Admin
condition:
  match:
   expr:  P.attr.abc_id in R.attr.abc_ids
```

But issue with above rule is that if a user have either `customer_user` or `api_user` it still get `EFFECT_ALLOW` for `read_funding_amount` action even though the user don't have `Admin` role, but I want the user to have an `admin` role in order to access that action.

Seems like the `abc_user` and `Admin` role is in OR condition here but I want them in And condition, how can I achieve this in Cerbos?